# How to convert CameraController's XFile to Image type in Flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, dart, camera

Flutter's `CameraController` has a `takePicture()` method for taking picture from the camera which gives type of `Future<XFile>`, so I need to convert it to `Image` type from `package:image/image.dart` package to manually crop it with another method.

How to convert it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is my found solution:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

...

CameraController _controller;

...

final xFile = await _controller.takePicture();
final path = xFile.path;
final bytes = await File(path).readAsBytes();
final img.Image image = img.decodeImage(bytes);
```

Comment: No need to create a `File`: `final bytes = await file.readAsBytes(); return decodeImage(bytes);`

Comment: The argument type 'Future<Uint8List>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<int>' - I get this error using this method

Comment: Is there a way to load Image type from ``'package:image/image.dart'`` to Image widget from Flutter? I'm having trouble with this as the app kept showing Exception: invalid image data.

Comment: This does not work for web because File is not supported consistently –

Answer (score 21):

You can get the path from XFlie by using .path property and then show image using

```
Container(
  child: Image.file(File(XFile.path)),
);
```

Comment: OP asked for Image type, not presenting Image path in Widget

Comment: This does not work for web because File is not supported consistently

Answer (score 4):

Two different solutions than the answers adopted:

1. Use [cross_file_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cross_file_image) dependency.

   ```dart
   import 'package:cross_file_image/cross_file_image.dart';

   Image(image: XFileImage(xfile));
   ```
2. Call `readAsBytes` method.

   ```dart
   import 'dart:typed_data';

   import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
   import 'package:cross_file/cross_file.dart';

   Future<Image> xFileToImage(XFile xFile) async {
     final Uint8List bytes = await xFile.readAsBytes();
     return Image.memory(bytes).image;
   }
   ```

   ```dart
   Image(image: await xFileToImage(xFile));
   ```

Comment: Great Job Terry

Answer (score 1):

You should use cross_file_image package and the bellow code :

```
import 'package:cross_file_image/cross_file_image.dart';

Image(image: XFileImage(xfile));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the cross_file_image package.

then do the following:

```
Image(image: XFileImage(xfile));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).