# Convert image file into base64 image in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, image, dart, base64, converters

I am using the flutter camera plugin to take pictures from my app using the camera device and send them as base64 images on the server.

When I want to convert the generated image into a base 64 image I can perfectly do it from my android emulator with this line :

```
base64img = base64Encode(File(image.path).readAsBytesSync());
```

"image" is a XFile.
"image.path" is a String.

When I try to use the same line on the web I get this error :

> Exception caught by gesture
> ═══════════════════════════════════════════ The following
> UnsupportedError was thrown while handling a gesture: Unsupported
> operation: _Namespace

I tried with this line (directly trying to convert the XFile instead of converting a generated File from the image path String) :

```
base64img = base64Encode(image.readAsBytesSync())
```

I get the same error.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution, using readAsBytes instead of readAsBytesSync :

```
var bytes = await widget.image.readAsBytes();
var base64img = base64Encode(bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:image/image.dart';

String imageToBase64(File file, {int? height}) {
  final image = decodeImage(file.readAsBytesSync())!;
  final resizedImage = copyResize(image, height: height ?? 800);
  return base64Encode(encodeJpg(resizedImage));
}
```

Comment: for installing - package:image
`flutter pub add image`

Comment: Tried it, I got this error : "The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
'readAsBytesSync'
Dynamic call of null.
Receiver: Instance of 'XFile'
Arguments: []"

Comment: In this case, you need to convert to the required type, here is an example
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68081428/8155939

Comment: Same error, converting the path to a File is what I already tried to do.